# How to use -v awk option for filtering out lines from a file

Tags: shell, variables, awk

I have a text file with the format

```
key01=value
key02=value
...
keyN=value
```

And I would like to retrieve the value for a specific key number. I made it work using a  literal, but it failed when trying to use the `$SEARCHKEY` variable as input for search. For example:

```
$echo $SEARCHKEY
KEY02

$awk -F= -v "searchKey=$SEARCHKEY" '/KEY02/ {print $2 " => " searchKey}' \ 
./parameterValue.lst
```

Output:

```
BBBB => KEY02
```

However, I cannot make it work when I change the `/KEY02/` literal by `searchKey`:

```
awk -F= -v "searchKey=$SEARCHKEY" '/searchKey/ {print $2 " => " searchKey}' \
./parameterValue.lst
```

Returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F= -v "searchKey=$SEARCHKEY" '$0 ~ searchKey {print $2 " => " searchKey}' input
```

variable are passed as strings into awk when using the `-v`-flag.
`/searchKey/` hence searches for the string "searchKey" To prevent this, use the regex matching operator `~` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**You should avoid doing regex matching here since it can give you unexpected errors as `/key02/` (or `$0 ~ searchKey`) can also match `key022` and give you wrong results.**

Instead of regex match you can use equality check to match literal key by

```
awk -F= -v searchKey="$SEARCHKEY" '$1==searchKey{print $2 " => " searchKey}' inFile
```